# std::bind on operator[] of std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, bind, function-reference

I am trying to bind a member function at or operator[] of std::array, but the compiler (gcc 7.3) says that it can't determine the typename _Func. So I had created my own struct array to see where the problem is. But it works fin in this case.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

template<typename ret, unsigned int size>
struct my_arr {
    ret data[size];

    ret& at(unsigned int i) {return data[i];}

    ret& operator[](unsigned int i){return data[i];}
};

using namespace std::placeholders;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    my_arr<int,3> ma = {1,2,3};

    auto x = std::bind(&my_arr<int,3>::at, _1, 0); // ok

    auto x1 = std::bind(&my_arr<int,3>::operator[], _1, 0); // ok

    auto arr_x = std::bind(&array<double, 3>::at, _1, _2); // error

    auto arr_x = std::bind(&array<double, 3>::operator[], _1, _2); // error

    std::cout << x(ma) << std::endl << x1(ma) << std::endl;

}
```

The compile error is:

> no matching function for call to 'bind(, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const
>   std::_Placeholder<2>&)'
>      auto arr_x = std::bind(&array::at, _1, _2);
>                                                            ^

---

I have realized what causes this error, but I still don't know how to solve it. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know which function do I reffer to, because there are const and non-const variants of these functions. This code simulates the same error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

template<typename ret, unsigned int size>
struct my_arr {
    ret data[size];

    ret& at(unsigned int i) {return data[i];}
    const ret& at(unsigned int i) const {return data[i];}
    ret& operator[](unsigned int i){return data[i];}
};

using namespace std::placeholders;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    my_arr<int,3> ma = {1,2,3};

    auto x = std::bind(&my_arr<int,3>::at, _1, 0); // error

    auto x1 = std::bind(&my_arr<int,3>::operator[], _1, 0); // ok

    std::cout << x(ma) << std::endl << x1(ma) << std::endl;

}
```

I still don't know how to specify which version of function I want to call, how to bind the const version and the non-const one?

Comment: Fwiw, just use a lambda: `auto foo = [&ma](auto some_param){ return ma[some_param]; };`

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but let me point out that `operator[]` and `at` are not equivalent. `at` performs bounds checking and is therefore safer and less efficient.

Comment: @Tom I have written the answer so please take a look at it and give it an upvote and / or accept it (that green tick beneath the votes) if it helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have two overloads:

- `ret& at(unsigned int i)` and
- `const ret& at(unsigned int i) const`

compiler doesn't know which function overload you really want to bind to. Therefore, you need to cast function pointer to the exact function signature.

This would work:

```cpp
auto x = std::bind(static_cast<int&(my_arr<int, 3>::*)(unsigned int)>(&my_arr<int,3>::at), _1, 0);
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:103,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:103,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:5,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:21),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+ret,+unsigned+int+size%3E%0Astruct+my_arr+%7B%0A++++ret+data%5Bsize%5D%3B%0A%0A++++ret%26+at(unsigned+int+i)+%7Breturn+data%5Bi%5D%3B%7D%0A++++const+ret%26+at(unsigned+int+i)+const+%7Breturn+data%5Bi%5D%3B%7D%0A++++ret%26+operator%5B%5D(unsigned+int+i)%7Breturn+data%5Bi%5D%3B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std::placeholders%3B%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++my_arr%3Cint,3%3E+ma+%3D+%7B1,2,3%7D%3B%0A%0A++++auto+x+%3D+std::bind(static_cast%3Cint%26(my_arr%3Cint,+3%3E::*)(unsigned+int)%3E(%26my_arr%3Cint,3%3E::at),+_1,+0)%3B+//+error%0A%0A++++auto+x1+%3D+std::bind(%26my_arr%3Cint,3%3E::operator%5B%5D,+_1,+0)%3B+//+ok%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+x(ma)+%3C%3C+std::endl+%3C%3C+x1(ma)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

You can also solve your problem in a more elegant way by using lambdas:

```cpp
auto x2 = [&ma](auto const p) { return ma.at(p); };
std::cout << x2(0) << std::endl; // output: 1
```